# Saving values for later use

Tags: c#, arraylist, save, ini

Case: I'm creating a program which reads values out of plc's. In order to read these values, a configuration tab is filled in. This configuration tab puts all his values into a arraylist. If the program closes, it loses all his configuration data, i want to make a function to keep this configuration data. I'm completely new to such things and i'm curious if you guys might have an answer and/or example code. I was thinking of storing the complete arraylist, and read out when i open this ***.whatever*** file.

As you might have seen, ive created a menu already.

Arraylist name = allData.

The arraylists accepts this data in an object named: DataPerLabel.

Configuration tab:

[image: Configuration tab]

Class DataPerLabel:

```
class DataPerLabel
{
    public String labelName;
    public String labelAdress;
    public String dataType;
    public bool monitor;

    public DataPerLabel(String labelName, String labelAdress, String dataType, bool monitor)
    {
        this.labelName = labelName;
        this.labelAdress = labelAdress;
        this.dataType = dataType;
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    public String getLabelName()
    {
        return labelName;
    }

    public String getLabelAdress()
    {
        return labelAdress;
    }

    public String getDataType()
    {
        return dataType;
    }

    public bool getMonitor()
    {
        return monitor;
    }
}
```

I want to store this arraylist in an .ini or .txt fil

I've now tried this:

```
private void menuItemSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string yourFilePath = @"C:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\Desktop\\WindowsHMI\\";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataPerLabel));

        foreach (DataPerLabel configRecord in allData)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(yourFilePath, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, configRecord);
            }
        }
    }
```

Gives me the error: Serialization not possible on allDataPerLabel because it does not have a constructor without parameters.

Hope anyone can help,

Thanks

Comment: You should look into saving your files into app.config or a user config file using  the [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Let me check it out, as i said im completely new and student so, thanks anyway!

Comment: Storing the entire arraylist in a file is easily done using serialization and loading it again at startup using deserialization. But I would rather go with @MarkusDeibel suggestion of storing the data in a config file. If the data in the configuration tab is different for each user, I would store the data as user settings, if it's the same for every user I would store them in the config file.

Comment: Answered you with the fastest solution

Comment: As an aside, `ArrayList` is a non-generic collection which is pretty much entirely superceded by `List<T>`. I'd strongly encourage you to use generic collections in almost all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way!

Using:

> https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Store the list:

```
List<DataPerLabel> lst = new List<DataPerLabel>();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
File.WriteAllText("path", json);
```

Read the list:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("path");
List<DataPerLabel> lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataPerLabel>>(json);
```

Comment: In what type of file i need to store the json object? or does it automaticly create one?

string path =  @"C:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\Desktop\\WindowsHMI\\";

wont work right?

Comment: it will create a txt file, you should specify the path\\filename

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data as xml string:

```
List<DataPerLabel> _dataPerLabelList; // this is your data object.

.
.
.

// on saving:

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataPerLabel>));

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(yourFilePath, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
{
       serializer.Serialize(writer, _dataPerLabelList);
}

.
.
.


// on loading your form:
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataPerLabel>));

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(yourFilePath))
{
      _dataPerLabelList = (List<DataPerLabel>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

**Note**: Since your list contains objects from the same type then I think that there is no need to use `ArrayList`, and you can just use `List<DataPerLabel>` instead.

Comment: When loading my forms, how do i put all this data into the same arraylist allData?

Comment: Since your list contains only one object type then I think it's better to user List<> instead of ArrayList .